# Ruby on rails. Monthly subscription best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subscription, braintree, rake-task

Hello I have a monthly subscription on my app using Braintree which is working ok. I would like some advice on best practices for the event where payments aren't made on time for whatever reason.

I currently have a `User` model with `subscribed:boolean` `subscribeddate:date` and `subscribedend:date`.

When a user completes payment through braintree, the attributes get updated to `subscribed:true` `subscribeddate:Date.today` and `subscribedend:Sometime_way_in_the_future` .

When a user cancels a subscription, the attributes get updated too, `subscribed:false` and `subscribedend:(a braintree attribute, billing_due_date)`

This way I can filter things in my app according to dates and subscription status. The only problem I can see with this is if Braintree tries to charge an account one month but fails. Braintree has an attribute for this (`.days_past_due`), but my app has no way of knowing whether this has occurred or not.

What are the best practices for this? Should I do a scheduled task each day to check if every single user has a value for the `.days_past_due` attribute on the Braintree server? Would this not be incredibly slow if I have a lot of users?
I may be going about this all wrong and I'd just like a bit of advice on the matter,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact support@braintreepayments.com.</sub>

Your best bet is going to be to implement Braintree's recurring billing **webhooks**. [Webhooks send you a notification](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/webhooks) via HTTP POST whenever an event occurs that may not have been directly triggered by an API call—such as a customer getting charged via their subscription, a subscription getting canceled, or a subscription going past due. This will allow you to directly respond to subscription events, without having to perform daily checks to see if any changes have occurred.

To use webhooks, you need to choose which events you want to receive webhooks for, designate an endpoint on your server where we'll send the notifications, and set up that endpoint with code to parse the webhook notification into a useable form. For details, see this [guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/overview) with instructions.

Comment: Found out about the webhooks after posting this. I now have them implemented. Thanks.